# laravel-5 How can i specify tags which not be escaped by blade?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, redactor

I am using Laravel and imperavi redactor on my website.
How can i specify list of the tags which will be not escaped by Blade?

For example redactor using tag p and if i just escape all data it will be unformatted, without paragraphs. But i need some tags for formatting and still want to be safe from XSS injections. Is laravel have an ability to do this or i need to use some other stuff?
Of course i can {!! $data !!} data but if i do this all data will be unescaped and it's scary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blade either will escape all or nothing. Only choice is to use your own or 3rd party parser that will escape needed tags for you.

One package that might help you is https://packagist.org/packages/mews/purifier